# VSCode で PHP ファイルの編集時、名前の一括変更ができない

Tags: php, vscode

VSCodeを使って、phpのコードを書いています。
変数や関数の名前の変更をしようと思っています。

「F2キーを押す」と説明されているサイトが多いのですが、
実際にF2キーを押しても、何も反応がありません。

変数にカーソルがある状態、変数を選択した状態、いずれも反応なしです。

Ctrl＋F2をクリックすると、文字列変更になります。
スコープを無視してすべての文字を変更するので利用できません。

```php
function sample1(){
  $result = 1; //＜＝これを変更
  return $resutl;
}
function sample2(){
  $ResultSample = 2;
  return $ResultSample ;
}

/// resutl を hoho にすると、次のようになってしまう
function sample1(){
  $hogehoge = 1;
  return $hogehoge;
}
function sample2(){
  $hogehogeSample= 2;
  return $hogehogeSample;
}
```

ちなみに vue の編集においては「変数にカーソルがあるとき（選択はしない）、f2キー」でスコープ内変数名を変更することはできています。

なにか設定があるように思えるのですが、検索エンジンでの検索では見つけることができませんでした。
拡張など必要なものがあるのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

拡張機能の [PHP Tools for Visual Studio Code](https://www.devsense.com/ja) をインストールすることで解決しました。

vscode で PHP言語で開発する際に必要な拡張のようです。

[php 使用するオペレーションシステム Windows (Wikibooks)](https://ja.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP/#Windows)

PHP開発のためにたくさんのページを参考にしましたが、この拡張が紹介されているページには出会っていませんでした。実際に検索しても、日本語ページでは先程のWikipediaともう1件しかありません。

そのため、他の拡張で「F2で変数名、関数名変更」ができる可能性があります。

【追記】

「できた」と、喜んでいたのですが「名前変更は有料版のみ」でした、
どうりで利用者数が少ないはずです。

この事例から考えると、vscodeのphpでは「スコープ内の名前を同時変更はできない」と考えるほうが良さそうです。

Answer (score 0):

VS Codeで <kbd>F2</kbd> は `editor.action.rename` が割り当てられているはず
php 利用の際, 別のコマンドが `when` の指定で有効になってるのかもしれません
(キーボード・ショートカット (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) で参照すると分かるかも)

`editor.action.rename` を実行するならコマンドパレット (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>)を開き コマンド ID をコピペするとよいでしょう

あるいは他の手段として

- 現状のキーボード・ショートカット(の割り当て)から <kbd>F2</kbd> を復活させる
- もしくは別のキーに `editor.action.rename` を割り当てる
- マルチカーソルを利用する (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> などその他)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。キーボードショートカットの設定から editor.action.rename（日本語 シンボルの名前変更）は設定されていました。vueでは使えていたのでこれが機能していると思います。editorHasRenameProvider を除くと良いとあったのでやってみました。"editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"に変更後、再起動もしたいのですが、それでF2をクリックしてもも何も反応してくれません。

Comment: 同じwhen条件の ctrl+f2 は動作します。別な原因がありそうです。

Comment: ためしにキーをshift+f2に変えてみました。vueの方はshift+f2で名前変更になりましたが、phpはこの場合も何も反応しません

Comment: PHP Tools for Visual Studio Code を追加したら、編集できるようになりました。この拡張の利用数が1M未満と少なくて、スルーしていていました

Comment: まずコマンドパレットで実行できるかどうか試してみては？